# getting MS Excel document properties using Java

Tags: java, excel-2010, aspose-cells

Please refer to the https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEdkd.png. The file is an MS Excel file encrypted with a password.

I am using Aspose Cell to parse this. Before I can do that, I need to get some metadata specified in the custom properties. 
Is there a way to get this using Java?

In this example, I want to get "e99y" by providing "myName".

The sheet can belong to any of the users. I want to embed the property myName/e99y so the system will know which user the sheet belongs to. Then, it'll look up the correct password from the system to encrypt and open the sheet.

Thank you!

Comment: You should at least specify which metadata/custom properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try the following sample code if it works for you:
e.g
**Sample code:**

```
// Creating an XLS LoadOptions object
LoadOptions loadOptions = new LoadOptions(FileFormatType.EXCEL_97_TO_2003);

// Setting the password for the encrypted Excel file
loadOptions.setPassword("1234");

    //Instantiate a Workbook object
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook("C:\\book1.xls", loadOptions);

    //Retrieve a list of all custom document properties of the Excel file
    CustomDocumentPropertyCollection customProperties = workbook.getWorksheets().getCustomDocumentProperties();

    //Accessng a custom document property by using the property name
    DocumentProperty customProperty2 = customProperties.get("myName");
```

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Hi, Amjad. Thanks for your answer. I might have missed something in the description. The sheet can belong to any of the users. I want to embed the property myName/e99y so the system will know which user the sheet belongs to. Then, it'll look up the correct password from the system to open the sheet. I greatly appreciate your answer.  Cheers!

Comment: If you need to add custom document properties, you may do that. Here is sample code: // Open Workbook metadata
MetadataOptions options = new MetadataOptions(MetadataType.DOCUMENT_PROPERTIES);
WorkbookMetadata meta = new WorkbookMetadata(dataDir + "Sample1.xlsx", options);

// Set a document property
meta.getCustomDocumentProperties().add("myName", "e99y");

// Save the metadata info in the output file.
meta.save(dataDir + "Sample1.out.xlsx");